# How to make joint on collision in box2d

Tags: c++, ios, box2d, collision

I detect collision in BeginContact function of the contact listener..

```
void MagneteListener::BeginContact(b2Contact* contact)
{
// I detect 2 needed bodies.
... 
b2RevoluteJointDef revDef;
revDef.lowerAngle = 0.0;
revDef.upperAngle = 0.0;
revDef.enableLimit = true;
revDef.collideConnected = false;
revDef.Initialize(body1, body2, body1->GetWorldCenter());
_world->CreateJoint(&revDef);
// End create joint
}
```

As a result program crashes with error

Assertion failed: (IsLocked() == false), function CreateJoint,

If i create joint with those 2 bodies after collision before next world step it works good.

```
_world->Step(dt, velocityIterations, positionIterations);
```

So the question is there any way to joint strait on collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should store the information required to create the joint somewhere in your program, and use it when `b2World::update` function returns

Comment: As i write in a question, i do it before the next step. So the correct way is detect collision, save information, than set contact->SetEnabled(false) and before next step to create a joint?

Comment: @Buron: I don't understand why you need to disable the contact. And yes, this is the only way since you can't create new bodies, fixtures or joints during simulation. In my projects I just saved all the collision information and processed it right after `update` returned